# Setting Tags on Azure IotHub using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am spinning up our environment using PowerShell scripts.  I use Tags to keep track of some useful tidbits across all Resources.

For most everything I can do something like this (skipping all the error checking and existing tags):

```
$resource = Get-AzureRmResouce -ResourceGroupName 'my-rg' -ResourceType 'microsoft.web/sites' -ResourceName 'my-app'
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -Tags @(${'tagname'='tagvalue';})
```

However, for IoT Hubs the above gives me:

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'
```

Some resources give me another mechanism, e.g.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name 'my-rg' -Tag ...
```

but I don't see that for IoT Hubs either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, IoT Hubs does not support add `Tags`. Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/17750752-iot-hub-doesn-t-support-tags-in-the-azure-portal).

If you want to manage your resource, maybe you could add tags to your resource group.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create new tags successfully by using the cmdlet of New-AzureRmResourceGroup:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name 'my-rg' -Tag @{key1="value1";key2="value2"}
```

please notice the data value format of Tag parameter (it is a hashs table),and then use Get-AzureRmTag to check the result:
[AzureRM Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBWS1.png)

BTW, the version of my AzureRM is 4.3.1, you can use under cmdlet to check the version:

```
Get-Module AzureRM -list | Select-Object Name,Version,Path
```

You can get more information from [Microsoft Azure New-AzureRmResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresourcegroup?view=azurermps-4.3.1)

Comment: That will add a tag to the resource group itself, but not to any of the resources attached to that group. my goal is to tag all resources that belong to the same "environment"